# How do I display tokens of a public key using Solana web3.js?

Tags: javascript, solana

Everybody on Solana network is generating tokens, making transactions. I don't want any of them, I just want to display tokens of a public key.
So far, I managed to integrate Phantom wallet to my website. I can get Solana balance(lamports) of connected account.

```
var accountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfoAndContext(publicKey)
```

returns only SOL balance. There is also a data variable on the response but It is null.
If it's not possible to get token data from web3.js, Is there a way to get it from Phantom wallet somehow? I mean If chrome is able to display this data on Phantom wallet, there should be a way to access it.